# Converting String consisting of octal numbers to UTF-8 text

Tags: java, android, utf-8, escaping, octal

Hello this is my first question on this site ever.
I'm making a program that converts text to octal, but also octal to utf-8 text again.

`150 145 154 154 157 40 167 157 162 154 144` should decode as `hello world`

Here is my code

```
source = source.replaceAll(" ", "");
int integer = Integer.parseInt(source,8);
List<Byte> queue = new LinkedList<>();
for (String s : source.split(" ")) {
    if (s != null && s != "") {
            for (byte b : s.getBytes()) {
                    queue.add(b);
            }
    }
}


Byte[] byteArr = new Byte[queue.size()];
byteArr = queue.toArray(byteArr);

byte[] b2 = new byte[byteArr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.length; i++)
{
    b2[i] = byteArr[i];
}

String answer = new String(b2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
edittextbinary.setText(answer);
```

It just returns the same octal value and does not decode.
I need help to extract the octal numbers and convert them to decimal and then decode to UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this could help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String octalString = "150 145 154 154 157 40 167 157 162 154 144";

  StringTokenizer tokeniser = new StringTokenizer(octalString);
  int len = tokeniser.countTokens();
  int[] octalArray = new int[len];
  byte[] octalByteArray = new byte[len];

  for (int i = 0; tokeniser.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
    octalArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokeniser.nextToken(),8);
    octalByteArray[i] = (byte) octalArray[i];
  }
  System.out.println(new String(octalByteArray, "UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider adding an explanation of your code, or what the actual problem might have been to improve the quality of your answer.